# install nfs on centos with a custom kernel

Tags: centos, nfs

I am trying to turn on nfs on Centos running a custom 2.6.22.9 kernel.  In the kernel config, under File systems, Network File Systems, I enabled as modules 'NFS file system support' and 'NFS server support'.  I did not enable any of the options under either of those options.

Then I compiled the kernel and installed the modules.  I did not reboot the server.  I installed the NFS module, and I can see it when I do an lsmod.

I have the following entry in my /etc/exports

```
/home/jon/nfs/     192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0(rw,no_root_squash,sync)
```

when I try and start nfs I get the following messages

```
[root@gw linux]# service nfs start
Starting NFS services:                                     [  OK  ]
Starting NFS quotas:                                       [  OK  ]
Starting NFS daemon:                                       [FAILED]
[root@gw linux]#
```

/var/log/daemon shows

```
Jun 16 10:19:34 gw nfsd[16031]: nfssvc: Function not implemented
```

rpcinfo shows

```
[root@gw linux]# rpcinfo -p localhost
program vers proto   port
100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
100024    1   udp   1011  status
100024    1   tcp   1014  status
100011    1   udp    942  rquotad
100011    2   udp    942  rquotad
100011    1   tcp    945  rquotad
100011    2   tcp    945  rquotad
[root@gw linux]#
```

How do I get this going?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NFS functionality comprises of two portions:

- NFS file system support (client)

  The module for this is called **nfs**
- NFS server support

  The module for this is called **nfsd**

The error you're getting indicates that you may have only loaded the client module.

Comment: My assumption, base on the line Starting NFS daemon: [FAILED], is that when I run service nsf start I start the deamon.

I tried starting the deamon from the command line via /usr/sbin/rpc.nfsd and I recieved the same message.

Comment: That was it.  I loaded module nfs, but I needed nfsd